# Is it possible to compare 4 variables at once?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictor

I have data set for one year it should looks like this example. For some points, C will be same, because they lay in same areas of concentration.

```
ID   elevation[m]   distance[km]      ndvi      C[ug]
1      250             0.980         -0.02       12
2      270             1.25          -0.16       12
3      390             4.5            0.72        8
```

My question is can I compare them togather, at once? Because I want to find if there is any relationship, between this variables. At NDVI and C I was playing with Spearman's ρ. 
And also I just stared learning R and statistic.

Comment: The question is unclear as asked. What do you mean by compare? Do you want to see which variables predict some dependent variable? Do you want to view correlations between all pairs of variables? What is the analysis you hope to conduct (i.e. what are you trying to do)?

Comment: Im not looking or developing predictiv model. So the second, to view correlations between all pairs of variable.

Comment: In that case this is less a question about statistics, and more a question about how to code in R, unless you have a deeper question than how do you display the correlation matrix of a set of variables. I only mention this because it may be a better question for stack exchange not cross validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is about comparing multiple variables together, at once. So I'll mention other methods to handle multivariate data.

You might measure multivariate correlation. It is described, for example, in [Measures of Linear Correlation for Multiple Variables](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4827v2):

> multivariate linear correlation coefficient (LCC) and linear
>   incorrelation coefficient (LIC), to measure the strength of
>   multivariate linear correlation and linear irrelevance

Another measure that might be interesting is the [partial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation) which we can think of as a measure of the correlation between variables after discarding the linear influence of other variables.

Answer (score 1):

To show all pairwise correlations in  R, assuming your data frame only has these 4 variables and your data frame is named dat, all it takes is

```
cor(dat)
```

It will show the pearson r value by default. It will not give you signficance levels. You can check them against a [critical value table](http://www.gifted.uconn.edu/siegle/research/correlation/corrchrt.htm) or you can use `cor.test()` for single pairs of variables. You can also change the type of correlation using the `method` parameter.

```
cor(dat, method="spearman")
```

This will give you spearman correlation values.

If your data frame has more variables, you merely need to select the ones you want, e.g. dat[,1:4] will select the first 4 columns of the data frame.